# Microdata ItemID to identify elements scattered throughout an HTML doc/HTML tables

Tags: microdata, schema.org

My developer coded a list of Products using HTML Tables. The code came out something like this:

```html
<table>
<tr  class="name">
<td>Product Name #1</td><td>Product Name #2</td><td>Product Name #3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="price">
<td>Product Price #1</td><td>Product Price #2</td><td>Product Price #3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="brand">
<td>Product Brand #1</td><td>Product Brand #2</td><td>Product Brand #3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You get the idea.  Visually it looks perfect, but when attempting to markup via schema.org, I'm running into issues, being that the products properties don't exist is neat nested HTML elements, but are spread across the table.  Would there be a way to use the `ItemID` Microdata attribute to make sure each brand and price is associated with the right product name?

Something like:

```html
<tr class="name">
<td itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product" itemID="Product1">Product Name #1</td>
<td itemscope itemtype="http://www.scema.org/Product" itemID="Product2">Product Name #2</td>
```

Etc., etc.  Any thoughts? Will I have the re-code the pages to make this work?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `itemid` is the right way to do this. Your example would look something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr class="name">
    <td itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product" itemid="Product1">
      <span itemprop="name">Product Name #1</span>
    </td>
    <td itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product" itemid="Product2">
      <span itemprop="name">Product Name #2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="price">
    <td itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product" itemid="Product1">
      <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="price">Product Price #1</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product" itemid="Product2">
      <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="price">Product Price #2</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By re-using the same `itemid` you're telling the microdata parser that you're talking about the same item in different parts of the page.

Comment: [`itemid`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#attr-itemid) "must have a value that is a valid URL".

Comment: @unor relative URLS are valid itemids

Comment: With this method you get 4 products, 2 with name only and another 2 with offer only. Use this tool to test it https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/

Comment: Using the newer [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), which makes use of the `itemid` attribute, this markup correctly produces 2 Products.

Comment: @ShawnSimister as unor suggested, shouldn't the itemid point to a URL. Whenever i use a numeric value e.g a product SKU then google's Data testing tool shows www.example.com/XXXX . Im confused here how to proceed and what the example.com implies

Comment: The `itemid` property (`@id` in JSON-LD) [is used](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/wiki/How-to-use-Multi-Typed-Entities-or-MTEs#are-there-other-ways-to-indicate-mtes) to define MTEs (Multi Typed Entities). If your products are not multi-typed you _should be_ using `itemref` as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409122/712334).

Answer (score 8):

Actually, `itemid` would not be the correct way to do this. Unlike RDF, the microdata parsing model doesn't join things that have the same `itemid`.

Instead, you should use the itemref attribute.

For example:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="foo"></div>
<div id="foo" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <span itemprop="price">Product Price #1</span>
</div>
```

You can test microdata using https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/microtest/ in addition to Google.

Comment: According to the [`automotive` example](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/blob/d366aa26f86d87963e066912b640316ab1f0173b/docs/automotive.html#L573) on schema.org you are more correct.